# Strange ZIP codes in Alaska?

Tags: maps, alaska

Most ZIP codes in the US are fairly familiar - 5 digits, like 90210.

However I've come across some weird ZIP codes in Anchorage - like 995MX.  ([Visible on this map](http://alaska.hometownlocator.com/zip-codes/countyzips,scfips,02020,c,anchorage,map,1.cfm))

Many websites (like google maps) don't accept this as a valid ZIP. Even clicking on it on the map above claims it's a "filler"? Where did this come from? Why are there these unusual ZIP codes around there, and do they have a 'normal' ZIP code alias?

Comment: Interesting question... but... is it really travel related? :)

Comment: Well it's a real problem I faced mapping a trip to Anchorage, so yes, I think so... ;)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about postal services, not travel.

Comment: @gerrit literally found it by trying to google a zip code of a place I wanted to visit, as per my above comment.  Nothing to do with postal services.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Maponics](http://www.spatialinsights.com/catalog/product.aspx?product=1249&content=3999) who provide data for many mapping tools, would appear to be the source of this - for as they state in their documentation:

> ZIP Codes
>
> This product includes the names and boundaries (and other attributes
>   as Maponics may choose to provide) for postal ZIP Codes in the United
>   States. Maponics’ proprietary process builds these polygons using
>   multiple data sources. The ZIP Code boundaries are based off of the
>   carrier route boundaries, using a combine/dissolve/extend approach.
>   Because there are cases where carrier routes do not exist, the ZIP
>   Code boundaries have been extended using a proprietary process so that
>   ZIP Codes cover the entire US. However, there are intentional holes in
>   the ZIP Code layer for major water and landmark areas. In all cases
>   where carrier routes exist, the ZIP Codes share the border line with
>   carrier routes.
>
> There are some areas where there is not sufficient data to create ZIP
>   Code polygons. Where possible, Maponics has created temporary ZIP Code
>   areas and **given the area a ZIP Code starting with the three digit ZIP
>   Code followed by either an “MH” or “MX” (ex. 901MH) to differentiate
>   area encompassed by water (“MH” ) or land (“MX”).** Other such areas
>   appear as holes. Some unique ZIP Codes might appear as polygons (for
>   example, a university).

Answer (score 12):

Zip codes were not allocated to these areas. When needed, MX will be substituted by numbers when the zip code is allocated for a portion of the "filler" area. See for example 99691 within the 996MX area.

Alaska is huge and very sparsely populated. No point in allocating zip codes for areas where no-one is going to send any mail.

Comment: Do you have a source for this?  Not that I don't believe you, I'm just interested in reading more.

Comment: Can't find it right now, but I remember reading it in some article about the zip codes history... Did you know that "zip code" is trademarked?:-)

Comment: Wiki claims that "The term ZIP code was originally registered as a servicemark (a type of trademark) by the U.S. Postal Service, but its registration has since expired." :/

Comment: well... it shows how old that article was... No wonder I can't find it now:)

Comment: Nope, I've found it.  Going to answer in a second.